# Getting null when using MockClient

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, mocking, mockito

For my unit testing, I am using [mockito 4.1.4](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) like this:

**I am having a test that is passing if I am using this code:**

```
    test('Adding data manually', () async {
      final GhibliFilms ghibliMock = GhibliFilms();

      ghibliMock.addFilm(FilmModel(
          director: 'test director',
          description: 'test',
          releaseDate: 'test',
          producer: 'test'
      ));

      expect(ghibliMock.films.length, 1);

    });
```

GhibliFilms addFilm method:

```
  List<FilmModel> _films = [];

  void addFilm(FilmModel film){
    _films.add(film);
  }
```

---

### A problem

I want to use `MockClient` to control some data manually, but when I am using it my test will fail:

This is my MockClient:

```
class MockClient extends Mock implements GhibliFilms {
  @override
  Future<List<FilmModel>> getFilms() async{
    return null;
  }
}
```

And when I change `final GhibliFilms ghibliMock = GhibliFilms();` to `final MockClient ghibliMock = MockClient();` (the rest of the code remained the same) my test will fail with this message:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length
```

**What is wrong with my approach? and how can I use MockClient for my case?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You made a `Mock` of `GhibliFilms` but didn't stub its `.films` getter, so by default it will return `null`. `expect(ghibliMock.films.length, 1);` therefore results in a null pointer exception.
2. If your `getFilms` override was meant to override the `.films` getter instead, your override explicitly returns `null`.  It's not clear what purpose this is intended to serve.
3. [Adding overridden methods to a `Mock` is an anti-pattern](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito#best-practices).

It seems that you want something like:

```dart
test('Adding data manually', () async {
  final MockClient ghibliMock = MockClient();

  when(ghibliMock.films).thenReturn(FilmModel(
    director: 'test director',
    description: 'test',
    releaseDate: 'test',
    producer: 'test'
  ));

  expect(ghibliMock.films.length, 1);
});
```

but note that that test is completely uninteresting since it doesn't test anything about your actual class.

`class MockClient ... implements GhibliFilms` means that `MockClient` provides the `GhibliFilms` interface but provides its own, completely separate implementation.  The purpose of `Mock`s isn't to replace the class you're testing; it's to replace objects that the code you're testing *depends on*.

If you're trying to replace a single method in an your `GhibliFilms` class, then you instead should just `extend` it and override the specific method you want.  For example:

```dart
class FakeGhibliFilms extends GhibliFilms {
  @override 
  Future<List<FilmModel>> getFilms() async {
    return [
      FilmModel(
        director: 'test director',
        description: 'test',
        releaseDate: 'test',
        producer: 'test',
      )
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: When you are using `when(ghibliMock.films).thenReturn..` does it mean that when `.films` is called you are returning a custom value?

Comment: Yes, `when(...).thenReturn(...)` creates a stub that returns the specified value.  See the [mockito documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito#how-about-some-stubbing).